# Getting "Error loading player: No playable sources found" with Chromium

Tags: firefox, chromium, browser, media, konqueror

I'm trying to play the audio program available [here](http://www.iba.org.il/program.aspx?scode=2065184) on my Kubuntu 16.04 (but under LXDE).

Results:

- Mozilla Firefox: It works fine.
- Google Chromium: I get this error message:

  ```
  Error loading player: No playable sources found
  ```

My question is mostly about Chromium. Why am I getting that message and how can I fix it?

Comment: sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer http://askubuntu.com/questions/579616/video-player-not-working

Comment: @monks: I don't have root; and the sysadmin doesn't want to install flash at all. But perhaps that's another question. Can you flesh out  your comment into an answer, explaining the cause?